# When an association is specified with class name, how do you access it? Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So lets I have a Transactions model.

Transactions.rb has:

```
 belongs_to :buyer, :class_name => "User"
 belongs_to :seller, :class_name => "User"
```

The user logged in, is accessed with current_user.

How can I do something like current_user.transactions? (which won't work as transactions doesn't have a user_id column) Or something like current_user.transactions.buyer?

Thanks!

(also the user model has_many :transactions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All associations in Rails are one-way.

So for each `belongs_to`, you need to add a `has_many` or `has_one` on the other side.

I'd suggest you want something like this;

```
class User
  has_many :transactions_as_buyer,
    :class_name => "Transaction",
    :foreign_key => :buyer_id

  has_many :transactions_as_seller,
    :class_name => "Transaction",
    :foreign_key => :seller_id
end
```

Now you can say;

```
current_user.transactions_as_seller.map(&:buyer)
```

to get an array of buyers.

Of course, depending on your app you may have a better name than "transactions_as_buyer/seller"